# Will U.S brokers accept a utility bill as a proof of residency if it is not registered in my name?

Tags: united-states, brokerage, know-your-customer

Will U.S brokers accept a utility bill as a proof of residency-address (when opening account) if it is not registered in my name?

Comment: Why not ask the brokerage itself?

Comment: How would a bill in your father's name prove that you are a resident?

Comment: Are you a minor (under 18 years old)?

Comment: If your name isn't on the bill then it isn't proof that you reside at the billed address.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, only your broker can answer this question. I would ask them directly.

Most proof-of-residence documents require both the address and *your* name. If your name is not on the utility bill then they probably won't accept it. Your best bet is to provide a government ID, some sort of school enrollment document (if you are a minor or at college), or a pay-stub. Again, it has to include both your address and your name.